# Closure of Infinite Bounded Set

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

**Problem** Let $S$ be a bounded infinite set and let $x = $ sup $S$. Prove that if $x \notin S,$ then $x \in S'$, where $S'$ denotes all accumulation points of $S$.

**My Proof** Since $x = $ sup $S$, this means for any $x - \epsilon$ where $\epsilon < 0$, there exists an $s > x - \epsilon$ where $s \in S$. This implies that for any $\epsilon > 0$, the deleted neighborhood $N$ centered at $x$, or $N^*(x ; \epsilon)$ intersects $S$, meaning that $x \in $ cl $S$ = $S \cup S'$. As $x \notin S, x \in S'$.

I'm not sure if my proof is acceptable. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I have never seen this notation before: "$N * (x ; \varepsilon$": what does it mean?

Comment: Sorry I made a typo. It means the deleted neighborhood of x.